# Force put in python queue even when full

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a thread that reads frames for a webcam and put them in a queue. Then another thread reads the frames as needed.

My problem is that I want to keep the latest frames in the queue even if the consumer thread cannot keep up.

I can do the following in the thread queuing frames:

```py
if q.full():
    drop = q.get()

q.put(new_frame)
```

But I think this can fail in to ways.

1. If the queue was full when `full()` was called but then the consumer fetches frames, the producer will discard a frame for no reason.
2. If the queue was full when `full()` was called then the consumer fetches all frames from the queue, the producer will freeze on q.get(). Basically breaking the application.

In my case, would using `threading.Lock` with a simple list be the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that should be useful. Put a request to acquire the lock at two places, one before the function where the frames are fetched and one after checking the condition if the queue is full.

After you check that the queue is full and you have acquired the lock then you can check the condition again whether it is still full or not. With respect to this condition you can decide whether to call the `get` function or not.

```
Thread 1:
if q.full():
    // acquire lock
    if q.full():
        drop = q.get()
    else:
        q.put(new_frame)
    // release lock
else:
    q.put(new_frame)
```

```
Thread 2:
if not q.empty():
    //acquire lock
    q.get()
    // release lock
```

Comment: Just a note. This code assumes that only Thread 1 will place items on the queue. If there are multiple threads which will put items on the queue, you must acquire the lock before ever checking `q.full()`. Otherwise after you check it the first time, the other thread could fill the queue and the `q.put` will block.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a non-blocking put queue

```
from time import monotonic as time
from queue import Queue
from collections import deque

class NonBlockingPutQueue(Queue):

    def put(self, item, block=True, timeout=None):
        with self.not_full:
            self._put(item)
            self.unfinished_tasks += 1
            self.not_empty.notify()

    def _init(self, maxsize):
        self.queue = deque(maxlen=maxsize)
```

Comment: This code completely ignores its `block` and `timeout` arguments, as well as completely ignoring the queue's `maxsize` parameter. If you wanted to just not have a maxsize, it would be far better to simply not *create* your queue with a maxsize.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @ranka47 answer and @sudo-bash comment

```
from queue import Queue

q = Queue(maxsize=5)
```

If you have multiple threads that can put new frames in the queue, you have to acquire the lock every time to ensure that put() will not be called while the queue is full (filled by a potential other thread).

Note that the default q.qsize() and q.get() are both using the queue lock (get() uses the lock in the non_empty condition), so we must use the non blocking equivalents.

```
def one_putting_thread():
    # acquire the queue lock
    with q.mutex:
        # check that the condition is still true. Because we acquired
        # the lock, we need to use the non blocking qsize method
        if q.maxsize <= q._qsize():
            # remove one element from the queue with the non blocking
            # get method. you can do something with the dropped frame
            drop = q._get()

        # put something in the queue
        new_frame = ...
        q.put(new_frame)

    # the lock is released when leaving the context manager
```

However, if you only have one "putting" thread, you can use q.put() outside the lock like that:

```
def single_putting_thread():
    # acquire the queue lock
    with q.mutex:
        # check that the condition is still true. Because we acquired
        # the lock, we need to use the non blocking qsize method
        if q.maxsize <= q._qsize():
            # remove one element from the queue with the non blocking
            # get method. you can do something with the dropped frame
            drop = q._get()
    
    # the lock is released when leaving the context manager

    # put something in the queue
    new_frame = ...
    q.put(new_frame)
```

Your reading thread could block on the get to wait for a frame to process:

```
def reading_thread():
    frame = q.get()
```